# Need your help for Android Alarms

Tags: android

I have different alarm buttons for providing notifications for different stuff at the same page. The problem occurs when I tried to set an alarm for first item , all text view will have the same time even thought I set an alarm for the first button only. May I get your help please? Thanks in Advance 
Here is the code

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_TIME:
        dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                // Alarm  for first item button
                editTextbreakfast.setText(DateFormat.format("h:mm a", c)); // show time in the box field                                
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(dailyhabitWithAlram.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(dailyhabitWithAlram.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // To have multiple alarms we need to add an ID to this intent , so each time it is linked to different alarm.
                AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi1);
                Toast.makeText(dailyhabitWithAlram.this, "Alarm has been set..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); /// this to notify the user that the alarm is set
                // Alarm for second item
                editTextSnack.setText(DateFormat.format("h:mm a", c));
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(dailyhabitWithAlram.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(dailyhabitWithAlram.this, 1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // To have multiple alarms we need to add an ID to this intent , so each time it is linked to different alarm.
                AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi2);
                Toast.makeText(dailyhabitWithAlram.this, "Alarm has been set..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
        break;
    }
    return dialog;

} // End of switch
```

Here is the AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the AlarmActivity

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this).setTitle("Task").setMessage("Time for    Breakfast").setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                AlarmActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the same `c` instance to set the time for the two `AlarmManager.set()` calls (unless you change the time specified by `c` between the two calls).

*Also, as an aside, there is no need to get the `AlarmManager` twice. `alarmManager1` and `alarmManager2` will be the same instance.*

Comment: I am new in Android, I tried to use different "c" instance but still the same problem. Could you explain more?

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for the [Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. You are probably simply continuing to assign the exact same time to the 2 alarms. You have to figure out how to specify the 2 different times -- you have not told us the characteristics of the 2 different times, so there is no way that anyone can help you further.

Comment: Thank you.I took a look at the Calender class , I will try to fix this bug.